# How to print the sum of columns and the index when the sum is not 0?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe similar to this structure:

```
     a      b      c    
1    0      1      0
2    0      0      0
3    1      0      0
4    0      0      0
5    0      0      0
```

I want to know if the sum of each row is != 0, so I try to use a for loop iterating each row and sum them with the builtin `.sum()` function and check if the condition applies.
The problem is that 99% of the data (>200,000 records) is filled with 0s, and my goal is to know which index whose sum is > 0.
Ive tried this

```
for x in range(len(people_killed)):
    print("Checking row"+str(x))
    if people_killed.iloc[x].sum() == 0:
        people_killed = people_killed.drop(x, axis=0)
```

but it will take a long time to get through every row.

What would be the best way to do this?
Thanks a lot beforehand!

Comment: Most of your questions are open. Please consider closing them by accepting the answer that resolves your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sum and then find nonzero indices as follows:

```
np.flatnonzero(people_killed.sum(1))
#[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
people_killed[people_killed.apply(sum, axis = 1) != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a brief logic about this problem . You must not find the sum of each element in the row but if there are all the positive numbers then just find a single number greater than 0 .That is when you iterate the loop stop the loop until you find a number greater than 0 .The sum of row will not become zero .

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: *How to print the sum of columns
(in each row)*, run:

```
people_killed.sum(axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

The left column is the index and the right column - sums for each row.

And as your second question is concerned, note that:

- `people_killed.sum(axis=1).ne(0)` generates a *Series* of *bool*,
  answering the question: *Has this row a non-zero sum?*
- `people_killed[people_killed.sum(axis=1).ne(0)]` retrieves all
  rows with sum != 0 (an example of *boolean indexing*).

So to get your result only one addition is needed: Retrieve **only the
index** of these rows:

```
people_killed[people_killed.sum(axis=1).ne(0)].index
```

The result is `Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')`, so it is a list
of index values of the "wanted" rows, not integer positions of these rows
(as the solution by *Ehsan* generates).
My solution computes just what you asked for: **indices**.